# Generating barcode for a field value in CRM 2011 reporting

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, barcode, bids

I want to generate a barcode based on the value of a field in a form. I have installed the **free 3 of 9 code** both on my sql server and my crm server. The field which I want to be converted to barcode has the font set to code 39 in BIDS and it shows correctly when I generate the report.

The issue is that when I import the report to CRM as .rdl file extension and run it, the report shows the actual field value and not the barcode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this](http://www.zeninteractions.com/free-reporting-services-barcodes) tutorial and changed the barcode to an image using systems.drawing library. CRM now shows the image as barcode.

Just FYI I used the code 3 de 9 barcode font. 
Cheers!

Comment: Please delete the dead link, and if it's possible add the tutorial directly on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the font on the client computer?  SSRS reports are initially rendered as HTML, so if you do not have the font, it may be displaying a default font.

Have you tried rendering it as PDF?

Comment: I have installed it on the CRM server. 
No i have not and how would rendering it on pdf make a difference?

Comment: I thought that PDF embedded fonts, but apparently that is not always the case: http://blogs.mtu.edu/gradschool/2010/04/27/how-to-determine-if-fonts-are-embedded/

Comment: The only issue is when i preview the report in CRM, it does not show the bars.